# makemigrations doesn't detect changes in model

Tags: django, migration

I'm using django 1.9.6. I recently deleted my migrations and ran `migrate --run-syncdb` and `makemigrations my_app`. Today I added a new field to one of my models:

*models.py:*

```
value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
```

I tried to migrate the changes, but `makemigrations` doesn't detect the change. It's just the development version, so I can resync (I don't have to preserve the data), but running `--run-syncdb` again doesn't detect it either.

Why isn't this migrating?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should not delete migrations, you should [squash them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing). If you simply deleted the files you likely messed things up, the easiest way to recover is re-sync your code to get the files back. A more complex route is to delete all the records from the `django_migrations` table and re-init the migrations from scratch but there is more steps/issues than I can really get into and I don't recommend it.

The reason makemigrations is not detecting the change is likely because there is no migrations folder in that app. If you run `python manage.py makemigrations your_app --initial` it might detect and generate the migrations or it might freak out because of the difference in your files and the `django_migrations` table.

The `--run-syncdb` command is great when you don't care about the data, usually before you actually deploy but once you start using migrations you should not use the `--run-syncdb` command anymore. For instance, during initial development here is the code I run every model change instead of dealing with migrations:

```
dropdb mydb && createdb mydb && python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb && python manage.py loaddata initial
```

I store all the initial data in a [fixtures file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/) and the command wipes out the entire database, the `--run-syncdb` rebuilds the schema, and the initial data is loaded while skipping actual migration files.

So, if you don't care about any of your data or can easily move it to a fixture than you can drop and re-create the DB. You are then free to delete all migration folders and you can use the command above until you go live and need to move to using migrations.

*** UPDATE FOR DJANGO 1.11 *** STILL USING ON 3.2.5 ***

I started using Django 1.11 and noticed the test framework can fail if you have dependencies on framework models and don't actually have migrations. This is the new command i'm using to wipe everything out and start over while still developing.

```
set -e
dropdb yourdb
createdb yourdb
find . -name "migrations" -type d -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
python manage.py makemigrations name every app you use seperated by space
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py loaddata initial
```

I put this in a `builddb.sh` at the root of my project (next to manage.py) so I can just run `./builddb.sh`. Be sure to delete it on deploy so there is no accidents!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation of the Right Way To Do It™. For anyone else trying this using `django.contrib.auth`, don't forget to `./manage.py migrate auth` too.

Comment: The squash link is broken unfortunately

Comment: If you put `set -e` at the top of your `builddb.sh` script you will be able to put all the lines one after the other without having to use &&. The `set` causes the entire script to stop on the first error.

Answer (score 25):

Delete every past migration files and __pycache__ files except __init__
then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations yourApp
```

After that make sure that the db is the same as the code in model.py (remove new changes) and run next line:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Now add all your changes in the model.py and run next lines:

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Best Regards,
Kristian

Comment: That does nothing. Is there a way of securely reinitializing the database?

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue. I realised I had a property defined on the model with the same name as a field I was trying to add on the model. Ensure the model doesn't have a model property/method with the same name as the field you are trying to add.

Comment: This response was so accurate for me that is frightened. Thanks A LOT.

Comment: I found this answer after 3 hours of freaking out! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same here...this answer saved me HOURS.  Good catch, Liyosi! :)

Answer (score 17):

Try creating a `migrations` folder that contains an empty `__init__.py` file inside your app folder if there is no `migrations` folder already. And make migrations.

Comment: This was the issue on my end

Comment: In my case that worked, even when I had the app in installed_apps. I just change the models of the app for models folder. I guess that when we do makemigrations that folder should be created

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I created a new project and created an app. The `python manage.py makemigrations` returned `no change detected` although I had added a handful of models.
Found out that you need to manually add the name of your app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list inside your `settings.py` file. Unless you do that, no change in the migration of that app can be detected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the settings.py file was missing the app in which I created the new models. After declaring the app in the **INSTALLED_APPS** list in **settings.py** file, the command `python manage.py makemigrations` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deleting a model, and expecting the changes to be picked up in migrations, ensure that the model doesn't have a `*.pyc` still lying around.

Answer (score 0):

Another case is abstract classes. Make sure that your model’s metaclass **does not have** the `abstract = True` property.

Answer (score 0):

In my case makemigrations wasn't detecting changes in models. However "python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb" worked. But it wasn't permanent solution for every change I make.
So I created new project with same name, apps with same names. Copied files from old project folder to the new one.  Now makemigrations is working as expected.
Only drawback is that db.sqlite3 was reacreated.  I used DBBrowser to copy some data I needed from old db.sqlite3 to new one.