# django heroku makemigrations ignoring changes in models

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, heroku-postgres

I deleted two models from models.py, and when I run makemigrations and migrate locally, everything is fine. When I run makemigrations on Heroku, I get the following message, where Building and BuildingInstance are the models I deleted:

```
Migrations for 'hello':
0002_building_buildinginstance.py:
- Create model Building
- Create model BuildingInstance
```

When I run migrate, I get:

```
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598676/django-heroku-error-your-models-have-changes-that-are-not-yet-reflected-in-a-mi) and also tried squashing the migrations locally and on Heroku as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370660/makemigrations-doesnt-detect-changes-in-model). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You only have a ``default`` database or are you using a db router?

Comment: @Grimmy only the default

Comment: It usually helps to inspect the contents of the ``django_migrations`` table. Maybe something is out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

As I have written many times here, you *must not* run makemigrations on Heroku. Run it locally, commit the result, and then​ run migrate on Heroku.

Comment: I still get the same error when I follow those steps